# How to install erlang observer on Mac?

Tags: macos, erlang, elixir

I am trying to start an observer from erlang VM, but it's failing.

```
iex(1)> :observer.start
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function :wx_object.start/3 is undefined (module :wx_object is not available)
    :wx_object.start(:observer_wx, [], [])
    observer_wx.erl:68: :observer_wx.start/0
```

Which libraries I am missing here?

For Ubuntu its `sudo apt-get install erlang-observer` What is corresonding for Mac?

Comment: Did you try this https://gist.github.com/alfredbaudisch/68b99e84c058c82dc264

Comment: How did you install Erlang? I've never had this problem with `brew install erlang`.

Comment: @Dogbert I tried brew install elixir which installs erlang

Comment: What is the output of `brew info erlang`? Try running `brew reinstall wxmac`

Answer (score 3):

You have to upgrade `wxmac` for Erlang/OTP 20:

```
brew update
brew upgrade wxmac
```

Comment: I already have wxmac 3.0.3.1_1 installed. Still, it's throwing the same error.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read your question correctly. I recently had :observer.start crash and this helped.

Comment: Check out this question because it has the same error message https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37213282/undefined-function-wx-object-start-3

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, in case you are using MacPorts like I am, the following command fixed the error above for me:

```
sudo port install erlang +hipe +ssl +odbc +wxwidgets
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to uninstall erlang and install wxmac, after that install erlang again.

```
asdf uninstall erlang <VERSION>
brew install wxmac
asdf install erlang <VERSION>
```